# Select cells based on other column

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel I have the following situation:

_ A B

1 3 M

2 8 F

3 7 F

4 6 F

5 1 M

6 3 M

7 9 F

I want to select the maximum value from column A where column B is M.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this array formula, which needs to be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>

=MAX(IF(B1:B30="M",A1:A30,0))

Adjust the ranges to suit your data.